# Как лучше реализовать toolbar в соответствии с моими задачами?

Tags: android

Есть приложение в котором я работаю со списками входящих и исходящих сообщений, при нажатии на один из элементов данного списка, я перехожу на активити где показывается мое сообщение, кто когда отправил и тд. И вот на этом активити я хочу внизу сделать toolbar где буду кнопки, например ответить приславшему сообщение, удалить и может что-то еще. Я уже работал с slidingTabs, но здесь я не уверен что нужно делать именно slidingTabs. Я хочу сделать просто toolbar с кнопками, которые будут переходить на отдельное активити. Я долго думал что использовать активити или фрагменты, и пришел к умозаключению, что активити будет лучше так как у меня есть как входящие так исходящие и toolbar будет одинаковым для этих двух категорий сообщений. Этот вопрос я задал для того что-бы мне посоветовали как лучше реализовать этот тулбар, с фрагментами или активити. Не спорю что очень путано написано, но я надеюсь что я получу здесь хорошие советы и другую полезную информацию касательно моего вопроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если ты хочешь реализовать Toolbar возможно тебе это поможет http://www.ahotbrew.com/android-toolbar-example/

Почему ты решил что нужно делать именно slidingTabs?
Как я думаю так activity реализуется если страничка "статичная" например как в настройки/галерея/калькулятор, а фрагменты если у тебя вот что то типа такого http://global.drfone.biz/images/others/true-contacts.jpg или google chrome, play market